# ASA 5505 unable to open up ASDM or https://(router IP here)

Tags: router, cisco-asa

When I try to load our ASA's ASDM client I get the error "Unable to launch device manager from 192.168.10.1"

I have tried verifying HTTP is enabled and when I go to https://192.168.10.1 it no longer displays any pages.

I have verified that the correct ASDM file version is being displayed by checking the running config ect. For some reason I just cant figure out why this all of the sudden doesnt work. I know theres a bug after it hits 1 year of uptime but the router has been reset and still has the trouble.

I have verified it is not java by installing JRE6u7. I am also unable to browse to it from any system that used to have permission.

Currently do not have any smartnet coverage so unable to update ASDM but it is version 8.2 if I remember right.

Anyone have any ideas on what to do to get this working? i can still access it via the serial port and use the CLI this way.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What error message does your browser give?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that nobody has altered the ASDM port? Some people do this when they need to provide the VPN client access feature.

Comment: The page cannot be displayed and then gives me the option to work offline (or the instructions rather).

Comment: I am the onlyone that makes changes so if it was changed I was not aware of it. i've enabled it under that subnet on another port to see if that would work. but it did not change anything.

Comment: you have https enabled right? ip http secure-server. You only mentioned http.

Comment: HTTP was enabled correctly. Made sure it routed correctly and that HTTPS converted over. in the end it was a corruption somewhere in the ASDM setting and I resetup the asa5505. the other option was to pay the smartnet coverage and update the IOS/ASDM version (its a few revisions behind but this would have resolved it)

Answer (score 2):

I know this may be an obvious question, but have you verified that you are using the correct IP address to access the ASA?  Are you connecting via a VLAN that has management access?

Check the config for changes to these.